# Default web browser character encoding in php

Tags: php

Does anyone know how can I default web browser character encoding in php, which I hope all user drop in to the page with using character encoding western (ISO-8859-1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Before printing/echoing anything else** do this

```
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1');
```

This will change HTTP headers and will set the browser's default encoding to ISO-8859-1 for your page, unless the user specifies otherwise via browser's settings.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the character encoding by outputting the Content-Type header.

```
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1');
```

This will tell the browser to use this character set to read your pages.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of writing this header `header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1');` in each of your web applications you could add this simple line in your `.htaccess` file

[AddDefaultCharset iso-8859-1](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/core.html#adddefaultcharset)

It makes Apache to serve out always the charset header.

Otherwise you could set once for all the [php.ini directive `default_charset`](http://it.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.default-charset) to "iso-8859-1". On most web hosters is usually set to empty string.
In order to do this once for all you need either to access the server main `php.ini` file or get an hoster with `suPHP` that will allow you to use your specific php.ini file in the same way you use .htaccess files. (suPHP is used by almost every webhosters).